# Not getting email in users/me Twitter OAuth2 api response

Tags: authentication, email, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am using the generated access_token to etch user details for implementing Twitter Login in PHP website. i am getting id,username and name in response of the https://api.twitter.com/2/users/me api. But it does not return the email address of the user.

Can anyone help in letting me know how to get email in this Twitter API response, or, even from any other Twitter API

I have enabled/done the following in my App settings:

- Checked/Set the option “Request email from users” in User Authentication Settings > App permissions
- As required, I have also entered the App’s Privacy Policy URL and Terms of User URL.
- Scope used: tweet.read users.read follows.read follows.write offline.access
  Still I am unable to get email address in response.

Comment: Please check this comment https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/419#issuecomment-264560103 , I have get email after User authentication settings changes on twitter development portal.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter doesn't give user email in API V2.

Here is table what you can get from `/2/users/me`:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user

Answer (score 0):

You can get authenticated user's email by v1 API `account/verify_credentials`
with `include_email=true`.
Most v1 APIs are deprecated but this is still available. And you can use this until v2 alternative comes up.
See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials for the details.

To get user's email, you should turn on `Projects & Apps` > Your App > `Settings` tab > `User authentication settings` > `Request email from users` option on Twitter Developer Portal.